# ¿Por que el elemento hijo de mi div se desborda del elemento padre?

Tags: css, bootstrap, css3

el elemento #cita se desborda de su elemento padre, ya le he puesto padding, ajustado al 100% el width  otras cosas, aqui dejo el codigo y una imagen donde el elemento #cita se desborda. Lo que me gustaria hacer es que este elemento no se desbordara de su elemento padre y que fuera responsive. Muchas gracias...

```
#desc {
    display: flex;
    padding: 30px;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: justify;
    background-color: #30302f;
    border-bottom: 7px solid #0da5bd;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: white;
}

#desc p {
    width: 100%;
}

#cita {
    background-color: #424241;
    padding: 15px;
    border-left: 3px solid #949492;
    margin-left: 25px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[image: El Elemento que se desborda es el #cita, con un background y el border diferente]

Comment: Podría ser muy útil que también pongas el segmento en HTML o algún ejemplo con tu falla en Codepen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le estas indicando al elemento `#cita` que ademas de tener el 100% de ancho tenga 25px de margen a la izquierda, lo cual tiene todo el espacio que puede ocupar movido 25px.
Si el elemento cita es un `div`, con quitar `width: 100%` bastaria. Si no, añade `display: block;`

```
#cita {
    background-color: #424241;
    padding: 15px;
    border-left: 3px solid #949492;
    margin-left: 25px;
}
```